# Firebase Emulator - Spring boot - FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-tools

I have a spring boot app using a Firebase (Emulator) running in a docker container.
This is my configuration

```
   GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
   .create(new AccessToken(
   "mock-token", Date.from(LocalDateTime.now()
   .plusYears(1).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));

    FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setProjectId("my_project")
            .setDatabaseUrl("http://localhost:9000/")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options, "my_project");
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

running **FirebaseAuth.getInstance()**, i got this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. Available app names: my_project

What i am doing wrong?.

connect to firebase emulator from spring boot app.

Answer (score 0):

The `getInstance` call documentation reads:

`Returns an instance of this class corresponding to the default FirebaseApp instance.`

the initializeApp must not have set a default FirebaseApp instance.

What you can do it take the app returned by `initializeApp` and pass it in, like: `getInstance(myApp)`.

I'd also use the `useEmulator` function rather than setting the DB URL:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth